# Macro for copying from one excel file into another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to using macros and need some help copying rows from one excel file and pasting into another as columns. I've done the first row manually, while recording the macro and here is the code:

```
Sub Macro2()

Macro2 Macro

Range("D5:L5").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("New_SET_Data.xlsx").Activate
Range("B7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Windows("Original_SET_Data.xls").Activate

End Sub
```

This needs to be done for multiple rows, and worksheets within the original excel file.

Comment: so... maybe read your post again - and say out loud : whats expected? think about it.

Comment: What is not working correctly for you?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to automate this and have it loop through all the rows in one worksheet, then move on to the next worksheet. Is there something like a do while loop that would work?

Comment: What does "all the rows" mean? What is the logic? The same question for "move to the nest worksheet", what is the logic in what you try to accomplish? Why we ask these questions is because we have no clue what the SPECIFIC problem is, and we could therefore come up with unlimited "answers" that mights or might not help you with your SPECIFIC problem.

Comment: evaluate your logics step by step then update your post!

Answer (score 1):

Put your ranges, worksheets & workbooks in as variables, then it's easier to work out. Use the WorksheetFunction "Transpose" to change the data - something like this:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
Dim rngSource as Range, Dim rngDest as Range, rngTemp as Range
Dim varArray() as Variant

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Original_SET_Data.xls")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("New_SET_Data.xlsx")
'To work through all sheets in Original_Set_Data.xls, you can replace this line with a "For each ws1 in wb1.Worksheets" loop and put Next at the end.
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Whatever_The_Source_Sheet_Is_Called")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Whatever_The_Destination_Sheet_Is_Called")

'Find the Source Range & Next Available Destination Column
Set rngSource = ws1.Range("D5", ws1.Range("D60000").end(xlUp).Address)
Set rngDest = ws2.Range("IV7").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1)

'Loop through Source Range and Transpose Data

For each rngTemp in rngSource
     'Put values from columns D to L into an array
     varArray = ws1.Range(rngTemp, rngTemp.Offset(0, 8).Value)
     'Transpose data - there are 9 columns D to L so we resize the range to be 9 rows high
     rngDest.Resize(9,1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(varArray)
     'Move to next column in new sheet
     Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0,1)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It automates looping through a set of rows and transposing the data to the new spreadsheet... it can also be run on multiple WS1 sheets by looping through the wb1.Worksheets collection.